# New to ODBC in R (RStudio), and getting a failed to connect error?

Tags: database, r, odbc, rstudio

Working through a tutorial to pull database data with:

```
install.packages('RODBC')
require(RODBC)

myNewDB=odbcConnect("QV Training")
```

And I get the error:

```
In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=QV Training")
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=QV Training") : ODBC connection failed
```

Is 'QV Training' meant to be the name of a database that may no longer be present? 
How does R know where to look for the database anyway?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows (unsure of other OSes) you need to go into the ODBC Data Source Administrator, and add the data source. The ODBC Data Source Administrator is accessed via the 'Administrative Tools' section of Control Panel (in Windows 10 at least).

[image: ODBC data source administrator panel]
[image: create new data source panel]
[image: create a new data source to sql server panel]

The connection command is then simply

```
conn <- odbcConnect("QV Training")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcConnect("Oracle", uid="system", pwd="root", rows_at_time = 500)
sqlQuery(con, "select file_name,sum(bytes)/1024/1024 AS MB from dba_data_files group by file_name")
d <- sqlQuery(con, "select * from dba_data_files")
close(con)
```